# Flutter rating bar

Tags: flutter, dart, rating, ratingbar, rating-system

I'm working on Flutter code to do rating bar system, but all examples i seen here work with allow half rating only, for example 4.5 works perfectly but 4.7 goes 5 stars.
I want to draw 4.7 stars as 4 stars and 0.7 star.

I'm using [smooth_star_rating](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_star_rating) on flutter pub.dev

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am a bit late,
but I figured out a custom solution and I hope it works for you as well, and you can adjust it as you like.

For example if you want to use a star instead of a container just use a star shaped container or an icon I guess and clip it accordingly (I am using a different shape).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

class RatingProgressBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final double rating;

  RatingProgressBar({@required this.rating});

  @override
  _RatingProgressBarState createState() => _RatingProgressBarState();
}

class _RatingProgressBarState extends State<RatingProgressBar> {
  double rate1 = 0.0;
  double rate2 = 0.0;
  double rate3 = 0.0;
  double rate4 = 0.0;
  double rate5 = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    final rating = widget.rating;

    if (rating >= 1) {
      rate1 = 1;
    }

    if (rating >= 2) {
      rate2 = 1;
    }

    if (rating >= 3) {
      rate3 = 1;
    }

    if (rating >= 4) {
      rate4 = 1;
    }

    if (rating >= 5) {
      rate5 = 1;
    }

    // Set fraction for partial star
    if (rating % 1 != 0) {
      final int wholeRating = rating.floor();
      final double fraction = rating - wholeRating;

      if (wholeRating == 0) {
        rate1 = fraction;
      } else if (wholeRating == 1) {
        rate2 = fraction;
      } else if (wholeRating == 2) {
        rate3 = fraction;
      } else if (wholeRating == 3) {
        rate4 = fraction;
      } else if (wholeRating == 4) {
        rate5 = fraction;
      }
    }

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          ratingStar(rate1),
          ratingStar(rate2),
          ratingStar(rate3),
          ratingStar(rate4),
          ratingStar(rate5),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget ratingStar (double star){
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.w),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 26.w,
            height: 26.h,
            clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.r),
            ),
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              value: star,
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.amber),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
            ),
          ),
          Icon(Icons.star_outlined, color: Colors.white, size: 20.sp),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In your page or wherever you want to use it,

```
RatingProgressBar(rating: 4.7),
```

Cheers !!